# wpf binding to another control property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

so i have this usercontrol :

```
<UserControl x:Class="Client.SpectrumSpace"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Client" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="350">
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Width="350" Height="150" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1">
            <Rectangle.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Name="contextMenu">
                    <MenuItem Name="ctxItem1" Header="AntennaName" 
                              IsEnabled="{Binding MainWindow.availeableAntennas[0]}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Rectangle.ContextMenu>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

and as you can see im trying to bind the MainWindow.availableAntennas[0] property to the MenuItem.IsEnabled property

this is how i declared the array on MainWindow class:

```
public  bool[]      availableAntennas   = new bool[9];
```

my problem is that the IsEnabled property is always true and yes i double checked the availeableAntennas[0] is false, so what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I've always found this cheatsheet helpful: http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `"RelativeSource"` of the binding expression.

Cheers

Comment: i tried  IsEnabled="{Binding MainWindow.availeableAntennas[0], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" and it didnt work, am i doing it wrong again? :S

Comment: What is MainWindow you are referring to?! I think it should be "{Binding availeableAntennas[0], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}". When you are using the RelativeSource, the datacontext would be the object that is match with the relativesource expression. Also I am not sure about the public variable you have in your window class.

Comment: MainWindow is the main window of my program, the one which is launched on startup. and i tried to change the xaml code to the one you offered but its still the same

Comment: What is happening exactly? Why you defined a variable? to do what? could you please help me with the situation?

Comment: of course! i have 9 user controls that suppose to contain an "anteanna". now i have 9 different antennas and i want that when a user binds an antenna to a user control, it will not be available to use in the rest of the controls.

Comment: Sir you need a model-view. A class that inherits from DependencyObject and a dependency property as you may ask I will explain how to define it. You should set the main DataContext (probably in DataContext of the main window) to an instance of that object and bind all the user controls to that object. This way you will make it work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like it could be a few things or all of them:

- You can't bind to a field it must be a property - *public  bool[]      availableAntennas   = new bool[9]*,
- A typo - *availeableAntennas vs. availableAntennas*,
- The datacontext must be set(it's not apparent from your posting),
- The class you are bound to must implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: you are correct there was a typo in my code but it still didnt correct my problem, and by setting the datacontext you mean DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"? cuz i did that too with no success

Comment: In your UserControl's ctor, set its DataContext to the class you want to bind it to.  Also, this class (the data context) must implement INotifyPropertyChanged (I updated my reponse to include this).